# What are my provider options for setting up high speed access to our office?

Tags: networking, providers

Which network providers have you worked with that provide good service?

Comment: This will depend on where your office is and what you mean by "high speed". Where is your office, and what data rate (committed and burst) are you after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally depends on who your local phone and cable service providers are, unless you have enough money to invest in a larger connection than they can provide (T1 and up).

There's also satellite DSL, if you're not near a major city or town.